# ActiveX dll registration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I created a ActiveQt project using VS2015, but the generated 64-bit DLL cannot be found in the VS2015(Tools - Choose toolbox Items - COM components). I also clicked the button in the dialog and tried to load DLL manually, but I got error: "Self-registration for x.dll failed."

I tried to use the regservr32.exe in both system32 and sysWOW64, they all failed.

I noticed that the dll was successfully registrated because I can find the related items in the registry.

After that, I generated a 32bit DLL and it can be found in COM components. Then, I also clicked the button in the dialog and tried to load 64bit DLL, but the item in COM components is still a 32bit DLL. What's more, I didnt get the error.

What should I do?
Thanks

Best regards,
Vincent

Comment: I found a web [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194802/activex-in-winform). But I dont get what Alessandro Jacopson said.

Comment: VS is a 32-bit process so can only display and use 32-bit COM components.  It is not very clear why you can't develop and debug a 32-bit version of the client and then build the 64-bit Release version of it.  Which by the sound of it is what you are doing now.

Comment: Thank you, @HansPassant. But I found some 64-bit DLL in the COM components. So probably, it is possible to load 64-bit DLL into VS. Do you have any idea how to do it?